# Unexpected character '' in implementation file

Tags: f#

I have a F# file `test.fs` that contains nothing but a comment:

```
// test
```

When I try to compile it in Visual Studio, I get the following error:

> FS0010    Unexpected character '﻿' in implementation file [...] test.fs

I get the same error when I add some code or other content to the file. The error always occurs at the first non-blank line. Other files are still working, so I assume my compiler is working.

I use F# v4.1, Visual Studio v15.3.5, MSBuild v15.3.409.

What does the error message mean and how can I fix it?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Looks like a non-printable character somewhere near the beginning of the file. Open the text file in an editor that can show them, then delete the offending char. The usual suspect is a [UTF byte order mark](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Byte_order_mark) in an environment/OS that doesn't handle it well.

Comment: It was indeed a UTF8 BOM. Thank you!

Comment: I just wrote `#version 100` at the first line of a `simple.fs` (fragment shader) and showing the same error.